# WebStorm not loading specific tsconfig.json

Tags: typescript, webstorm

I have a project using the latest version of WebStorm 2020.3.1. I have multiple `tsconfig.json` files but I only need automatic re-compilation through WebStorm for one of them. I have configured as attached.

Strange thing is that running `tsc -p ./tsconfig-electron.json` works fine.

What is the issue here?

[image: WebStorm TypeScript compilation]

#### tsconfig-electron.json:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "commonjs",
        "target": "es6",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "outDir": "electron-dist",
        "rootDir": "electron-src",
        "removeComments": true,
        "strict": true
    },
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "dist",
        "src",
        "e2e"
    ],
    "declaration": true
}
```

Answer (score 7):

The IDE uses the nearest `tsconfig.*.json` current file is included in for compiling, traversing the folders hierarchy from current folder up to the IDE project root. The list of known `tsconfig*.json` name patterns can be configured in **Settings | Editor | File Types, TypeScript Config**.

Options passed in **Settings | Languages & Frameworks | TypeScript, Options:** are ignored if there are `tsconfig.*.json` files in project, so you can't pass your custom configuration file to the IDE using this field.

Related feature request: [WEB-21414](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-21414)

Answer (score 1):

My issue was slightly different but maybe it'll help someone who ends up on this page.

Straight to the point:

#### The "nearest tsconfig.json" that everyone refers to, and I especially mean the word "nearest", doesn't mean the tsconfig.json ON THE SAME LEVEL but at least at the PARENT LEVEL.

In my case, IntelliJ was struggling to recognise the `sub-module/tsconfig.json` file as the correct file for the `sub-module/subModule.ts`. See below:

```
<root>/
  - tsconfig.json
  - src/
    ...(regular project stuff)
  - sub-module/
    - subModule.ts
    - tsconfig.json
```

I've spent quite some time to figure this out. It's not mentioned anywhere by any documentation or comment. The solution was to put `subModule.ts` and all related files in another subfolder, so they sit one level down relative to the `tsconfig.json`.

**Solution**:

```
<root>/
  - tsconfig.json
  - src/
    ...(regular project stuff)
  - sub-module/
    - src/
      - subModule.ts
    - tsconfig.json
```